# Python Threads don't terminate

Tags: python, queue, python-multithreading

I have a program that calls a module that runs threads. Sometimes I want to run it several times and the threads don't seem to be terminating. Since they're not terminating, the total amount of active threads eventually crashes my program.  I've searched and followed examples, to no avail. I'm pretty new to python, so any help would be appreciated.

Here's the main program. The module is named print_num.py:

```
import threading
from queue import Queue

q = Queue()

def print_me(num):
    print (num)

def threader():
    while True:
        worker = q.get()
        print_me(worker)
        q.task_done()

def main():

    for i in range (2):
        t = threading.Thread(target=threader)
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()

    for i in range (4):
        q.put(i)

    q.join()

    for thread in threading.enumerate():
       print('-->',thread.name)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Then I run the program with this module:

```
import print_num

for i in range (3):
    print_num.main()
```

The output is below:

```
0
1
2
3
--> MainThread
--> Thread-1
--> Thread-2
0
1
2
3
--> MainThread
--> Thread-1
--> Thread-2
--> Thread-3
--> Thread-4
0
1
2
3
--> MainThread
--> Thread-1
--> Thread-2
--> Thread-3
--> Thread-4
--> Thread-5
--> Thread-6
```

I don't understand why the threads aren't terminating. The first run has the Main Thread and 2 others, then the second run has those two and two more, and so on. If I run it 500 times instead of 3, my program crashes.

Comment: your thread never exits: infinite loop

Comment: Thanks Jean-Francois. Is there a way to resolve this? In the threader, I think I need to change "While True" to something to be tracked, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: it's for you to decide when to exit the loop. _if_ you need a loop at all.